# Рефакторинг кода Javascript

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

Привет, учусь писать элегантный код javascript на простых примерах.
Чтобы вы изменили в этом коде, чтобы он, по-вашему, стал лучше? Спасибо.

```
        (function () {
            "use strict";

            /**
             * This function selects all elements on the web pagen by name of tag
             * and applies to each of the callback function.
             *
             * The first param - the tag of elements.
             *
             * The second param - the name of a function or an anonymous function
             * that will handle each found element.
             *
             * The third param: if the function is a method of object
             * and it works with the other properties of the object
             * then need to pass the object in the third argument.
             *
             * @param {string} tagName
             * @param {function} callback
             * @param {object} object
             * @returns {undefined}
             */
            var processElementsByTagName = function (tagName, callback, object) {
                if (arguments.length < 2) {
                    throw new Error('Not enough arguments');
                }
                if (typeof arguments[0] !== 'string') {
                    throw new Error('The first argument should be an element tag name');
                }

                var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName),
                        length = els.length,
                        i = 0;
                //if the second argument is the name of the method
                if (typeof arguments[1] !== 'function') {

                    if (typeof arguments[1] !== 'string') {
                        throw new Error('The second argument must be a function or method name of object');
                    }
                    if (typeof arguments[2] !== 'object') {
                        throw new Error('The third argument must be an object');
                    }
                    if (!(arguments[1] in arguments[2])) {
                        throw new Error('This method does not exist in the object');
                    }

                    while (i < length) {
                        object[callback](els[i]);
                        i += 1;
                    }

                }
                //If the second param is a function
                while (i < length) {
                    callback(els[i]);
                    i += 1;
                }

            };

            //select all the elements <strong/>, and hide them
            //with the use of an anonymous callback function
            processElementsByTagName('strong', function (el) {
                el.style.display = "none";
            });

            //And now try to pass an object method

            /**
             * Some class.
             *
             * @constructor
             * @this {Handler}
             * @param {string} color
             */
            function Handler(color) {
                this.color = color;
            }
            //The class has a method that accesses a property of the class (color).
            Handler.prototype.highligh = function (el) {
                el.style.color = this.color;
            };
            var handler = new Handler('yellow');

            //Select all the <span/> elements
            //and change the color of the text in each element
            processElementsByTagName('span', 'highligh', handler);

        }());
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r52jz4m3/1/)

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [критериями хороших вопросов по указанным меткам](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review)

Comment: Уж если вы пишете документацию в коде - пишите ее хорошо. В частности, зачем нужны параметры функций.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, так как это вопрос как раз по инспекции, можете все ваши замечания собрать и опубликовать как ответ :)

Comment: В js не нужно передавать функции как объект-атрибут, они сами по себе хорошо передается. Сама по себе функция не должна искать и обрабатывать элементы одновременно.

Comment: @Etki, не совсем понял комментарий, там же в примере функция тоже передается

Comment: @Etki, не понял тебя. 1. В функция предусматривает что ей будет передана в качестве параметра callback как обычная функция, так и метода какого-нибудь объекта. Это плохо?
2. "Сама по себе функция не должна искать и обрабатывать элементы одновременно" Так у меня же только поиск элемента, а обработка вынесена в callback.
Объясни подробнее, плис.

Comment: @pavelchervov, укажите назначения кода (что код делает и зачем)

Comment: @pavelchervov методы объектов передаются ровно так же, как и обычные функции (разве что с поправкой на возможную необходимость указания контекста, но тогда нужно передавать сам объект и заранее знать, что это за объект)

Comment: @Grundy, добавил описание, такой простой функционал, а так много описания :)

Comment: @Etki, понял тебя, что-то типа как контроль типов в php, когда функция/метод в качестве аргумента может принимать только объект определённого класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Кода намного больше чем результата.

Для сравнения, JQuery:

```
$('strong').css('display', 'none')
$('span').css('color', 'yellow')
```

Чистый js (в шутку называемый *"фреймворк VanillaJS"*)

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('strong'), function (el) {
  el.style.display = 'none';
})
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('span'), function (el) {
  el.style.color = 'yellow';
})
```

Все, что вы сделали - это обернули конструкцию `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('span'),` в другую функцию столь сложным способом - но при этом остались на том же уровне емкости языка, не добавив простых методов выполнения групповых операций.

### 2. Вызов метода объекта столь сложным способом

Проще всего передать метод объекта так:

```
processElementsByTagName('span', handler.highligh.bind(handler));
```

Вы же ради незначительного упрощения синтаксиса нагородили внутри вашей функции аж 18 дополнительных строчек кода. Это половина функции...

Скажите, а вы так будете писать внутри каждой своей функции?

Фактически, единственный недостаток `bind` - это необходимость указания контекста два раза. Если хочется от него избавиться - то самым простым способом будет обертка над `bind`.

### 3. Цикл while

Не надо так делать циклы, когда переменная цикла инициализируется задолго до самого цикла.

Надо хотя бы перенести ее по-ближе, ведь за пределами цикла эта переменная вообще, по сути, не имеет смысла:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < length) {
  callback(els[i]);
  i += 1;
}
```

Кстати, `length` тоже лучше бы перенести к циклу.

Но еще лучше - использовать `for`. Не надо бояться этого цикла - он для таких ситуаций и создан:

```
for (var i=0, length = els.length; i<length; i++) {
  callback(els[i]);
}
```

А еще лучше - использовать встроенные в язык функции:

```
[].forEach.call(els, callback);
```

Comment: там, кстати, два цикла, когда можно было одним обойтись

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, спасибо, вот это я понимаю рефакторинг!
Не использовал for - хотел следовать шаб­лону "единственной инструкции var".

Comment: @pavelchervov цикл `for` можно использовать и с переменной, объявленной в другом месте. Но лично я не вижу особого смысла в шаблоне "единственная инструкция `var`".

Comment: @pavelchervov но, в любом случае, установка начального значения переменной должна происходить не где-то там, а строго перед циклом.